# how to duplicate Odoo v8 database?

Tags: odoo-8

I've been trying to duplicate Odoo's datebase in order to create a production database and a testing one. How can I do this? Once this is ready, how do I know which database I am working at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do database related operation like create new , duplicate , drop, backup database or restore database from odoo ui it self.

```
http://server_address:port/web/database/manager
```

Here you will get all the option to manage database from ui.

Answer (score 0):

just click on database manager just below the password field of login page then you can see Menu Named 'DUPLICATE' just click on that then there are two fields write there the source database name and new(Duplicated) Database and then click on Duplicate button on header. It duplicates DB in Seconds